# Is it possible to determine if a function is called on a webpage from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Say my extension operates on Facebook and the page has a javascript function called hello. Is it possible to determine when the function hello is called on the page?

Comment: The answer to your question is: "Yes". Sometimes doing so will be more convenient than other times, depending on the code for the web page.